# Zend Guard Loader not getting enabled

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-cache, zend-optimizer

I am trying to optimize my Zend Application using a Zend Guard Loader in my Xampp Contol Panel. To install and configure this, I have done the following configuration settings.

I have downloaded Zend Guard Loader from [Zend Guard Loader](http://www.zend.com/en/products/loader/downloads#Windows) for PHP 5.6 and extract it in my **`D:/xampp/php/ext/Zend-Loader`**.

It contains **`ZendLoader.dll`** and **`php_opcache.dll`**.

And in my `php.ini` file, I have updated it as:-

```
zend_extension_nts=D:/xampp/php/ext/Zend-Loader/ZendLoader.dll
```

[As my php is **thread safe** enabled, and so used **zend_extension_nts**].

Also i have uncommented and modified:-

- **opcache.enable=1**
- **zend_loader.enable=1**

And now when I check it using php -v or using phpinfo(),Its not showing Zend Guard Loader enabled.
Any help would be appreciated.It taking a hell lot of time to configure it.Also 
If anyone knows the effective ways how to optimize the Zend Apllication,Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to load `php_opcache.dll` after `ZendLoader.dll`.

Also the directive `zend_extension_nts` should be `zend_extension`.  There is no `zend_extension_nts` and `zend_extension_ts` has been removed since PHP 5.3.0.

So you php.ini should have these lines:

```
zend_extension=D:/xampp/php/ext/Zend-Loader/ZendLoader.dll
zend_extension=D:/xampp/php/ext/Zend-Loader/php_opcache.dll

zend_loader.enable=1
```

Comment: I did all these steps but still it is not loading. Can you please update here more ?.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- Download VC++2008 x86 from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11895
- Install it and restart the webserver.

My version was PHP 5.6 nts on Win Server 2008 R2 Enterprise x64